# Find area inside first curve and outside second curve without drawing (radius of curvature)

Tags: integration, curves

Ok so i'm tired of drawing curve and it takes too much time to draw , is there any way to find the area without drawing ? (for both curve with loop and without)

None of my teacher have teached me how to do it without drawing so it make me wonder whether if it is possible . Random guessing only sometimes work.

Lets take an example , area inside $r1=1+cos(\theta)$ and outside $r2=cos(6\theta)$

How can i know if the curve have loop or not , and if it does how can i determine the lower limit and upper limit for the/each integral ?

Comment: That is not the best of examples, The region between those two curves has a very complicated shape with at least 5 separate pieces, one of which is quite complicated. You can graph them at [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). Just enter "r = 1 + cos theta" and "r = cos 6 theta".

Comment: Yeah i know i can manually draw or use software such as desmos and wolfram , i'm here looking for way to do it without drawing in case it is faster to do than drawing